# Git checkout sha1 of head reference is not a tree:

Tags: git, bitbucket-pipelines

[Git tree example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56c4C.png)

I use bitbucket pipeline to create a deploying script. Here's the part of it that I have a concern with:

...

- cd $LINODE_PROJECT_PATH
- git checkout $BITBUCKET_COMMIT
- npm install

...
Note that $BITBUCKET_COMMIT gives me the full sha1 (eg.: bc0696fa452f4e3b30aa65ffe38ad27d8d12cc37)

I'm trying to accomplish a script that "git checkout sha1" for my releases. I want it to use sha1 to be able to rollback using the sha1.

With the image of my tree in reference, when I'm executing the command either "git checkout a1ee863" or "git checkout bc0696f", I receive the following result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36TzP.png)

fatal: reference is not a tree: bc0696fa452f4e3b30aa65ffe38ad27d8d12cc37

As you can see I am able to checkout a89c212 and 7ca7f7f which are 2 earlier commits.

Is there a way to checkout the "last commit of a branch" with the sha1?

Thanks

Edit: weirdly enough, I am able to checkout the tip locally on my windows machine. Side note: the server uses linux

Comment: Sounds like you haven't pushed that commit.

Comment: In fact it was pushed, you can see origin/release/prod in the commit message... thanks for the comment tho

Answer (score 1):

I only had to use "git fetch" prior to "git checkout [sha1]".